# How to secure selected pages in web application

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I have requirement where we have to show same page (say homepage) for both guest as well as authenticated user. Some pages are shown only to authenticated users. I have done the following

**JSP**

link 1
     href="secure/homepage">homepage

link 2
    href="homepage">homepage

link 3
    href="secure/adduser">Add user

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/homepage","/secure/homepage"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView viewHomePage() {

}
```

**Spring security**

But the problem is that every time link 3 is called from page displayed after calling link 1. My url become {applicationContext}/secure/secure/adduser

Comment: You can add a filter to filter out page requests for authenticated and non-authenticated users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use absolute links to avoid the accumulation of URL prefixes.

The link should be written as :

```
<a href="<c:url value="/secure/homepage"/>">Link 1</a>
```

Comment: Thanks Serge, Can you please let me know the best practice for web app security, below is my requirement, Few pages are visible to all, few pages are visible to authenticated users only based on their role. Do i need to create separate pages for authenticated user and not-authenticated users. I am using spring mvc and security.

Comment: @SumitAgarwal : Not sure these are really the *best partices*, but what is currently done is to have some pages accessible only depending on role, and on in the pages accessible to all (or to different roles) have block protected at JSP level with `<c:if>` tags, or with the spring security dedicated tags.